# my css code isn't turning my navbar into a specific colour

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

this program is supposed to turn the navbar blue but it remains white, what should I do?
hint: it is bootstrap 3.4.1
hint: it shouldn't do anything so don't try to fix that

lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

```css
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="PH.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default bg-blue">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hungry Photos</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>The image Gallery</h1>
            <p>A collection of selected pictures from multiple photographers</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **navbar navbar-default bg-blue** . 
if not working create a new class and used an important tag for that.

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: red !important;
}
.navbar a{
   color: white !important; 
}
```

Comment: nav a {
  color: white !important;
}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default bg-blue">
```

Bootstrap classes don't support anything such as bg-blue. **It supports bg-primary for blue color.**

Try change the above class to this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default bg-primary">
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
navbar navbar-default bg-blue
```

Try removing the `bg-blue`. Can't see the definition of that css class, but by its name seems like it would override the background-color too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use !important if you want to override actual values

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: darkcyan !important;
}
.navbar a{
   color: white !important; 
}
```

Are you looking for this?

[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vahid_634/woj1egL3/8/)

Comment: @why_u_wanna_no_me_name if answer is helpful for you please accept/vote.

Comment: i cant below 15 rep

Answer (score 0):

When you are using navbar there will be few colours provided by Bootstrap team. NO need to assign css color for navbar-default.

You should add navbar navbar-default bg-primary for blue color when you are defining navbar.

You can check thi sfor more of navabr - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/